# How do you subtract two time values in military format in google apps scripts for a spreadsheet?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

One column is labeled **Checkin Time** and the other is labeled **Checkout Time** and finally I have a column that is labeled **Total Time Worked**. The cells in the Total Time worked column should subtract the time in the checkout time column from the time in the checkin time column. How do I do this in the script? The times in the checkin and checkout cells are in the military time format which I got from the timestamp upon the form submission.

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

From a Google Form?  Do you need to do it in the script?  If I'm reading this right, if your checkin timestamp is in column A, and your checkout is column B, you should be able to literally just do `=B-A` in the total time worked column C. Make sure to set the formatting of the cell to 'Duration', the default will give you HH:MM:SS format, but you can customize it if you just want the hours and minutes.